# Fastest way to sum digits using bit operations when summing color values

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

My particular case of summing digits deals with colors represented as integer. Java function `BufferedImage.getRGB` returns image in `0x00RRGGBB` format. I'm making a function that gives you grayscale (color independent) sum of colors on the image. Currently, my operation looks very naive:

```
   //Just a pseudocode
   int sum = 0;
   for(x->width) {
       for(y->height) {
           int pixel = image.getRGB(x,y);
           sum+=(pixel&0x00FF0000)+(pixel&0x0000FF00)+(pixel&0x000000FF);
       }
   }
   //The average value for any color then equals:
   float avg = sum/(width*height*3);
```

I was wondering if I could do it even faster with some bit-shifting logic. And I am mostly asking this question to learn more about bit-shifting as I doubt any answer will speed up the program really *significantly*.

Comment: You're not shifting the high bytes of the result down so you're technically summing R, G and B "separately", of course with a bit of carrying to the higher bytes, if any. Hence the result will be much larger than 0xFF. And one more point is that human sensitivity to red, green and blue is not the same, so you can't just avarage the 3 color elements to get a good grayscale representation

Comment: This is really just doing `sum += pixel`

Comment: @harold oh my... didn't even realise this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R, G and B do not attribute equally to the perceived intensity. A better way to sum things up than this:

```
sum+=(pixel&0x00FF0000)+(pixel&0x0000FF00)+(pixel&0x000000FF);
```

Would be, with the necessary bitshifting and weighing (assuming 00RRGGBB):

```
sum+= ((pixel&0x00FF0000)>>16) * .30 / 255
    + ((pixel&0x0000FF00)>> 8) * .59 / 255
    +  (pixel&0x000000FF)      * .11 / 255;
```

You might want to leave the `/255` part out here and replace the floating point numbers with scaled-up integer numbers (like 30, 59 and 11), bearing in mind that you'll need a `long` `sum` to prevent overflow to a reasonable degree.